# IF ELSE in sql query

Tags: sql, ms-access, if-statement

I would like to know what's wrong in this query. In fact I have 3 tables and the idea is that I have 4 dates date_vesting_1 to date_vesting_4, and I should check the Last completed date to compere it with another date. So I used If ELSE in the query to start from date 4 to date 1 but it crashes every time I excute.

Thank you in advance.

```
   IF ( (SELECT (c.Date_vesting_4) FROM D_plan_characteristics AS c ) is NOT NULL) 
SELECT 
             e.emp_id, e.emp_lname, e.emp_fname, e.effective_date As eff_date
FROM 
             R_employee As e INNER JOIN 
                                                            (
                                                            D_plan_characteristics AS c INNER JOIN D_collaborator_plan As p 
                                                                                            ON c.charac_plan_id = p.charac_plan_id
                                                            ) 
                    ON e.emp_id = p.emp_id
WHERE 
             ( (c.date_cessibility) < (c.Date_vesting_4) )
    ELSE IF ( (SELECT (c.Date_vesting_3) FROM D_plan_characteristics As c ) is NOT NULL) 
SELECT 
             e.emp_id, e.emp_lname, e.emp_fname, e.effective_date As eff_date
FROM 
             R_employee As e INNER JOIN 
                                                            (
                                                            D_plan_characteristics AS c INNER JOIN D_collaborator_plan As p 
                                                                                            ON c.charac_plan_id = p.charac_plan_id
                                                            ) 
                    ON e.emp_id = p.emp_id
WHERE 
             ( (c.date_cessibility) < (c.Date_vesting_3) ) 
   ELSE IF ((SELECT (c.Date_vesting_2) FROM D_plan_characteristics As c ) is NOT NULL) 
SELECT 
             e.emp_id, e.emp_lname, e.emp_fname, e.effective_date As eff_date
FROM 
             R_employee As e INNER JOIN 
                                                            (
                                                            D_plan_characteristics AS c INNER JOIN D_collaborator_plan As p 
                                                                                            ON c.charac_plan_id = p.charac_plan_id
                                                            ) 
                    ON e.emp_id = p.emp_id
WHERE 
             ( (c.date_cessibility) < (c.Date_vesting_2) ) 
    ELSE IF ((SELECT (c.Date_vesting_1) FROM D_plan_characteristics As as c ) is NOT NULL) 
SELECT 
             e.emp_id, e.emp_lname, e.emp_fname, e.effective_date As eff_date
FROM 
             R_employee As e INNER JOIN 
                                                            (
                                                            D_plan_characteristics AS c INNER JOIN D_collaborator_plan As p 
                                                                                            ON c.charac_plan_id = p.charac_plan_id
                                                            ) 
                    ON e.emp_id = p.emp_id
WHERE 
             ( (c.date_cessibility) < (c.Date_vesting_1) );
```

Comment: 1) "it crashes" it would be nice to know how it "crashes". Does it show an error? If so, what is the error? 2) Did you write this sql yourself? Cause it looks generated, and generated ugly. 3) `IF ( (SELECT (c.Date_vesting_4) FROM D_plan_characteristics AS c ) is NOT NULL)`, do you realize the `select` returns a dataset? Which record are you checking for `NULL`?

Comment: 1-the error is: Access didn't find the table or the query source \n 2- I wrotre it except the inner join of the 3 tables which is generated bu access \n 3- I am checking if the c.Date_vesting_4 is not NULL @HoneyBadger

Comment: But what is _the_ `c.Date_vesting_4`? This is a list of values.

Comment: It's a field in a table @HoneyBadger

Comment: You don't get what I'm trying to say. When you do `SELECT (c.Date_vesting_4) FROM D_plan_characteristics AS c` you get a list of values. You get all records from the table, for example: 20160101; 20170223; null; 20180612;null. So you can't say `IF([this list of values] IS NULL)`. I guess you're thinking it's executed row-by-row, but the statement is executed over the whole set. At the moment of execution, so to speak, there is not one value which you are checking for null, it's a whole list, SQL doesn't work that way.

Comment: Yeah you are totally right I just figured it out, I tried to add a where condition but it was complicated so I used the Nz() as suggested bellow. May you check if the new query is right. You can find it below in the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's simpler to just use one single query using coalesce:

```
SELECT e.emp_id,
       e.emp_lname,
       e.emp_fname,
       e.effective_date AS eff_date
FROM   r_employee AS e
       INNER JOIN ( d_plan_characteristics AS c
                    INNER JOIN d_collaborator_plan AS p
                            ON c.charac_plan_id = p.charac_plan_id )
               ON e.emp_id = p.emp_id
WHERE  ( ( c.date_cessibility ) <
c.date_cessibility < Nz(c.date_vesting_4, Nz(c.date_vesting_3,Nz(c.date_vesting_2,Nz(c.date_vesting_1,getdate()))))
       )
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it but there is an error which is Function  COALESCE not defined in the expression. What do you suggest? @reekeecast

Comment: Oh you're right! My apologies, I just assumed you were on SQL Server or something. I didn't see the access tag.  In access you may use Nested `IFF` or nested `Nz()`. For example `c.date_cessibility < Nz(c.date_vesting_4, Nz(c.date_vesting_3,Nz(...`

Comment: SELECT e.emp_id,
       e.emp_lname,
       e.emp_fname,
       e.effective_date AS eff_date
FROM   r_employee AS e
       INNER JOIN ( d_plan_characteristics AS c
                    INNER JOIN d_collaborator_plan AS p
                            ON c.charac_plan_id = p.charac_plan_id )
               ON e.emp_id = p.emp_id
WHERE  ( ( c.date_cessibility ) < Nz(c.Date_vesting_4, Nz(c.Date_vesting_3, Nz(c.Date_vesting_2, Nz(c.Date_vesting_1))))

       )

Comment: What do you think of this ? @reekeecast

Comment: Looks good, except Nz uses 2 parameters, so the last nested call should be like `Nz(c.Date_vesting_1, getdate())` or something accordingly

Answer (score 1):

It "crashes" because the syntax is way off that of Access SQL.

So locate a tutorial in Access and queries. You'll need a quite different approach than your current.

Answer (score 0):

Finally this is the answer:

```
   SELECT 
   e.emp_id,
   e.emp_lname,
   e.emp_fname,
   e.effective_date AS eff_date
 FROM   r_employee AS e
   INNER JOIN ( d_plan_characteristics AS c
                INNER JOIN d_collaborator_plan AS p
                        ON c.charac_plan_id = p.charac_plan_id )
           ON e.emp_id = p.emp_id
 WHERE  ( ( c.date_cessibility ) < Nz(c.Date_vesting_4, Nz(c.Date_vesting_3, Nz(c.Date_vesting_2, Nz(c.Date_vesting_1, ""))))

   );
```